# API to find whether a WLS domain is in locked state

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to find whether there exist some API which tells whether a given Domain in weblogic server is locked or not. Before deploying an application on a server we need to lock the entire domain because parallel deployment is not allowed.

There are many server level APIs which tell whether server is up and running or down. But I couldn't find any domain level APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following wlst script to check if the console is locked

```
connect('username','password','t3://server_name:7001')
cm=getConfigManager()
if cm.isEditor() == 1:
  print 'WebLogic console is locked !!'
else:
  print 'WebLogic console is NOT locked'
```